# Gatsby Cloud environment variables not working in production

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, gatsby, gatsby-cloud

In a Gatsby project hosted in Gatsby Cloud I'm passing an API key as an environment variables, but unfortunately it's not available...

The code looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Airtable from 'airtable';

Airtable.configure({ apiKey: process.env.AIRTABLE_API_KEY });

const base = Airtable.base('appKjIv7utFmqAkdT');

function Gallery() {...
```

You can see where I'm inserting the API key.

My gatsby-config.js looks like this (I'm loading dotenv on top):

```
require('dotenv').config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
});

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `wernergeller.com`,
    siteUrl: `https://www.yourdomain.tld`,
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-google-analytics',
      options: {
        trackingId: '123',
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-image',
    'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'images',
        path: './src/images/',
      },
      __key: 'images',
    },
  ],
};
```

Locally (`gatsby develop`) this is working well.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gatsby Cloud variables needs to be added in the dashboard. The URL is something like: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/dashboard/YOUR_ORGANIZATION_UUID/settings/general#env-vars

And visually:

[image]

You can add variables individually or in a bulk with `key:value` pair:

[image]

Keep in mind that if you have environment variables that [need to be accessed in the browser](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/local-development/environment-variables/#accessing-environment-variables-in-the-browser) rather than the server, you'll need to prefix with `GATSBY_`.

It looks that the Airtable configuration is set on the browser, so you will need to change the key to:

```
Airtable.configure({ apiKey: process.env.GATSBY_AIRTABLE_API_KEY });
```

Changing the environment variable accordingly in the process.env and in the Gatsby Cloud dashboard.

Test your site with `gatsby build` locally before pushing it because `gatsby develop` it's not a full representation of your built/compiled project.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ferran! So I'm calling the Gatsby Cloud variable GATSBY_AIRTABLE_API_KEY as well? (so including GATSBY prefix?)

Comment: Yes, that's the idea if you are using the variables in the browser-side. If the issue has been solved please consider accepting the answer to close the issue

Comment: Hi @FerranBuireu! I have followed your steps, but I am still getting undefined client-side, even after defining them in Gatsby Cloud and trying with both GATSBY_ and without. It works in development but not production